# Is enum a type in Java

Tags: java

I finally have a reason to implement an `enum` in Java and and find it to be an invalid type in 1.6. So I declare the enum as

```
public enum MyEnum = {A=0, B=1, C=3};
```

and get an error invalid type in Eclipse.

Comment: There are millions of code examples for enums online. You haven't tried to compare a single one because all of them would have fixed your problem. Next time, you should at least do a basic google search (like `java enum example`)...

Answer (score 7):

That's not how they are used. See examples at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html, such as

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

Java enums are much more powerful than in, say, C#. They're (almost) full-blown objects, and thus cannot be represented with just a number. They can however contain a number, and they do have an [ordinal number value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29).

You could have the number value with

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A(0), B(1), C(3);

    private final int number;
    MyEnum(int number) {
      this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry can't ans all responses at once so I'll respond to the 1st. Thanks to all some books don't mention "Enum" or "enum". Java enum definitly not eq to C/C++ or Pascal.

Answer (score 3):

Java `enums` are quite different to C and C++ `enums`. The biggest difference is that the `enum` constants are full-blown objects rather than compile-time integer constants.

In your example, `A`, `B` and `C` are objects. Therefore constructs like `A=0, B=1, C=3` are not allowed.

I recommend taking a look at the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

If you *have* to associate numeric values with `enum` constants, you can achieve a similar effect like so:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A(0), B(1), C(3);
    public final int val;
    private MyEnum(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Having done this, you can access the values using `MyEnum.A.val` etc.

Comment: you can, but they'd be part of the enum object, like in the [planet example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Correct phrasing might be "they are not numbers, but objects, that can *contain* numeric values"

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `enum` is a type, but it is incompatible with integers. Enum objects are closer to classes than to primitives, in that they can have methods, member variables, and so on.

Java lets you get the effect that you wanted by adding an `int` member to your enumeration, and initializing it differently for different enumeration members, like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A(1), B(2), C(3);
    int val;
    private MyEnum (int v) {
        val = v;
    }
    public int value() {
        return val;
    }
};
```

Now each member of your `enum` has a public method `value()` that returns the integer value associated with the corresponding element of the enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

you can't do this as you do. `enum` define in java in the following way

```
enum myenum{a,b,c,d}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum ModuleType {A,B,C}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: `enum` is technically not a type. Therefore you cannot define a variable of type `enum` as you have tried.

`enum` is a keyword to define an enumerated (abbreviated to enum) type which is a special data type.
Once an enum type is defined  (very much like how you would define a class), you refer to it using the name of the enum type. Please check the [enum types documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).